# Why object is getting tilted while orbiting in trackball controls, whereas not in orbit controls?

Tags: three.js

When I try to orbit in trackball controls the object is getting tilted while when I do the same in orbit control it is not getting titled. Can anyone explain to me why it's happening that way and how to lock it?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `OrbitControls`, `TrackballControls` does not maintain a fixed value for the camera's `up` vector.

This design decision leads to the mentioned behavior and also makes it possible for `TrackballControls` to transform the camera "around the poles".

Comment: Is there any way to play with the camera's up vector? and to lock the rolling!  @Mugen87

Comment: Um, not sure what you are looking for. But in any case you have to modify `TrackballControls` if you want to change the way `up` is modified. Or just use `OrbitControls`^^.